# On many applications, text is wrapped to half the screen width

Tags: cyanogenmod, text-layout

In Gmail, Reader etc., text is wrapped to about half the screen width. This is extremely annoying! Text-size is normal, and I can't find any global settings that would govern such a thing. Can anyone help me out? I'm using a Nexus S, CM7. 
[image: Screenshot of text wrapping problem]

Comment: As a temporary work-around, flipping the phone to landscape and then back to portrait restores the wrapping to the whole width of the screen.  It comes back if the app is killed off by Android and needs to be re-started.

Comment: @Chahk Thanks, that works, is this a CM problem then?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't run other custom ROMs since Donut :)

Comment: @Chahk Not even stock?

Comment: @fredley Nope.  The one time I did run stock was when I booted up my N1 for the first time. It was then promptly unlocked and cyanogenized ;)  My co-worker just bought a G2x which runs stock Froyo (2.2), and his Gmail app functions normally.  Could be something in Gingerbread (2.3).

Comment: @Chahk Thanks for the help, I'll do a bit of digging into CM7...

Comment: This seems like it might be related to images or HTML markup. GMail does the same weird wrapping for me when I get mail with image headers (LinkedIn notifications are doing it, for example), but plain text mail wraps normally. Haven't found a way to fix it yet myself.

Comment: @eldarerathis Are you using CM?

Comment: @fredley: Yep, CM7 on an EVO.

Comment: @fredley: This has been fixed in latest CM7 builds. I'm running 7.0.2.1 on my Nexus One and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with CM7 builds up until 7.0.2 after which it was fixed.